# Combining two QTransform maps

Tags: c++, qt, matrix

Combining two QTransform map operators gives me a result that is not what I expected. Could anyone possibly point out the problem? Thanks.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc; (void)argv;

    QPointF pnt(20, 20); // normal coordinate system has x pointing right and y pointing up
    // Would like to show it on a QImage of height 100, whose x points right and y points down
    int height = 100; // thus, I expect the point will at (20, 80) on the image.


    QTransform flip_y = QTransform::fromScale(1,-1);
    QTransform shift = QTransform::fromTranslate(0, height);
    QPointF flipped = flip_y.map(pnt);
    QPointF shifted = shift.map(flipped);
    qDebug() << "flipped " << flipped << " shifted " << shifted; // As I expected: QPointF(20,80)

    QTransform flipy_then_shift = shift * flip_y;
    QPointF combined = flipy_then_shift.map(pnt);
    qDebug() << "combined " << combined; // QPointF(20,-120) this is not what I expected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformations are not commutative (Tx * Ty is differente to Ty * Tx) so the order of interest in your case must be:

```
QTransform flipy_then_shift = flip_y * shift;
```

Output:

```
flipped  QPointF(20,-20)  shifted  QPointF(20,80)
combined  QPointF(20,80)
```