# Mirror Selected QGraphicsItems based on boundingRect center

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsview

For the life of me I can not seem to figure out how to mirror the selected QGraphicsItems based on their selected center? Each attempt I've tried makes the items eventually shoot off screen. I've recreated this same setup in 3d applications and got it work but i'm missing something and can't figure out it. Any help would be much appreciated. The end goal is to be able to click the Mirror button and it flip them back and forth like the image below...

[image]

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QColor
import os
import random


class ImageWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1500,1080)

        # controls
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(40,40,40))
        
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.graphicsView.setSceneRect(-4000, -4000, 8000, 8000)
        self.graphicsView.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

        # align actions
        self.mirrorItemsHorizontalAct = QtWidgets.QAction('Mirror Horizontal', self)
        self.mirrorItemsHorizontalAct.triggered.connect(self.mirror_items_horizontal)

        transformToolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar('Transform', self)
        transformToolbar.addAction(self.mirrorItemsHorizontalAct)
        self.addToolBar(transformToolbar)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphicsView)

        # Load images from subfolder
        self.create_shapes()


    def create_shapes(self):
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0)
        gradient.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        gradient.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))

        rectA = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,150,100)
        rectA.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        rectA.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        rectA.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 10, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
        rectA.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rectA.setSelected(True)
        rectA.setPos(-120,50)
        self.scene.addItem(rectA)

        rectB = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,70,35)
        rectB.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        rectB.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        rectB.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rectB.setSelected(True)
        rectB.setPos(150,-150)
        self.scene.addItem(rectB)

        rectC = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,120,75)
        rectC.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        rectC.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        rectC.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rectC.setSelected(True)
        rectC.setPos(400,70)
        self.scene.addItem(rectC)


    # Align
    def mirror_items_horizontal(self):
        items = self.scene.selectedItems()
        if not items:
            items = self.scene.items()   
        
        # Calculate the collective bounding box
        collectivePath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        for item in items:
            collectivePath.addRect(item.sceneBoundingRect())
        collectiveRect = collectivePath.boundingRect()

        # Calculate the horizontal center of the collective bounding box
        centerX = collectiveRect.center().x()

        # print('centerX:', centerX)
        # print('collectiveRect:', collectiveRect)

        # Debug
        cItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(collectiveRect)
        cItem.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0,128)))
        cItem.setZValue(-1000)
        self.scene.addItem(cItem)

        cItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 10, 10)
        cItem.setPos(collectiveRect.center() - QtCore.QPointF(cItem.boundingRect().width()*0.5, cItem.boundingRect().height()*0.5) )
        cItem.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255,255,0,128)))
        cItem.setZValue(-1000)
        self.scene.addItem(cItem)

        for item in items:
            local_offset = item.boundingRect().center().x() * 2.0
            global_offset = collectiveRect.width() + item.boundingRect().x() * 2.0
            print('scenePos', item.scenePos())
            print('boundingRect', item.boundingRect())
            print('boundingRect center', item.boundingRect().center())
            print('local_offset', local_offset)
            print('global_offset', global_offset)

            scaleTm = QtGui.QTransform()
            scaleTm.translate(local_offset, 0)
            # scaleTm.translate(global_offset, 0)
            # scaleTm.translate(645, 0)
            scaleTm.scale(-1, 1)

            tm = item.transform() * scaleTm
            item.setTransform(tm)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = ImageWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not considering that a transform is always applied to its origin point (`0, 0`), while you want to mirror the items based on a reference point, which is the center of the "selection".

The procedure to apply such transformations is:

1. translate to the reference point;
2. set the scale (rotation/shear/etc.);
3. reset the translation to its origin;

Then, there's another issue in your attempt, which originally confused me too. You are combining the new transform with the existing one, but that has to be done with extreme care, as explained in the documentation about the [`*` operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#operator-2a):

> Note that matrix multiplication is not commutative, i.e. `a*b != b*a`.

Unlike the common multiplication (for which we know that the order doesn't matter), due to the complex relations of transform matrices, this is not the case. Since the mirroring, which is based on the *current* transform (and can be mirrored and translated too), it has to be applied *before* it, so the order is actually inverted: `scaleTm * item.transform()`.
If you think about the order in which you would eventually map a point based on each transform step (map *from* the current, then map *to* the new one), it makes more sense (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65693178)).

Finally, note that, for consistency, you should always consider the full coordinates of the mapped point (not only the x) even if you're only applying an horizontal transform. Also, since `transform()` does *not* consider the item `scale()` and `rotation()`, you have to avoid them, and any further scale or rotation applied to the item has to be done within the current item `transform()` instead.

In the following example I've added a custom class to show the "selection" as a separate item, so that there's no cumulative drawing.

```py
class CollectiveRect(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setZValue(-1000)
        self.rect = QRectF()
        self.brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 128))
        self.center = QGraphicsEllipseItem(-5, -5, 10, 10, self)
        self.center.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 128)))

        self.hideAni = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'opacity')
        self.hideAni.setDuration(1000)
        self.hideAni.setStartValue(1.)
        self.hideAni.setEndValue(0.)

        self.hideTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True, 
            interval=2000, timeout=self.hideAni.start)

        self.hide()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect | self.childrenBoundingRect()

    def setRect(self, *args):
        self.rect.setRect(*QRectF(*args).getRect())
        self.center.setPos(self.rect.center())
        self.prepareGeometryChange()

        if self.hideAni.state():
            self.hideAni.stop()

        self.setOpacity(1)
        self.show()
        
        self.hideTimer.start()

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget=None):
        qp.setBrush(self.brush)
        qp.drawRect(self.rect)


class ImageWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def create_shapes(self):
        ...
        self.collectiveRect = CollectiveRect()
        self.scene.addItem(self.collectiveRect)

    def mirror_items_horizontal(self):
        items = self.scene.selectedItems()
        if not items:
            for item in self.scene.items():
                if item.flags() & QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable:
                    item.setSelected(True)
                    items.append(item)
            if not items:
                return

        # Calculate the collective bounding box
        collectiveRect = QRectF()
        for item in items:
            collectiveRect |= item.sceneBoundingRect()
        self.collectiveRect.setRect(collectiveRect)

        center = collectiveRect.center()

        for item in items:
            reference = item.mapFromScene(center)
            scaleTm = QTransform()
            scaleTm.translate(reference.x(), reference.y())
            scaleTm.scale(-1, 1)
            scaleTm.translate(-reference.x(), -reference.y())

            item.setTransform(scaleTm * item.transform())
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to break this down and explain the situation. I was going a bit nuts myself trying to sort this out. I was able to replicate this in 3D but struggled to figure out what was going wrong in 2d. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JokerMartini You're welcome! Note that I realized that my point about explicitly setting transformations for scale/rotation of the item wasn't appropriate: if `setTransform()` is internally set by the item, the result of applying the further transform for the mirroring may not be correct. This is partially related to the way items are created and their contents eventually mapped (as you probably know, the item position doesn't always match with its contents). One of the drawbacks of the extensibility of the Graphics View framework is that such situations are much more difficult to deal with.

Comment: I'll see if I can do some further testing on the matter, but there's an important aspect to consider: in most situations, it's generally preferable to create items that have their contents (the bounding rect) always aligned to a well defined reference point. When dealing with basic shapes, this normally means the top left point of the bounding rect (but sometimes the center is better, as I did with `self.center` above). This normally makes transform aspects more intuitive and problem solving/debugging way simpler.

Comment: I actually discovered that using `scaleTm.translate(reference.x(), reference.y()); scaleTm.scale(-1, 1); scaleTm.translate(-reference.x(), -reference.y())`  cause issues with the items bounding box and later on it's ability to be aligned. I dumbed down the code you made and found a more reliable solution but not without the guidance of what you had done. ill post it

Answer (score 0):

The code below ended up working best for me. When i would apply 'translate' to the Transform' it would actually cause all sorts of issues when trying to get the objects pivot and left edge for later trying to do AlignLeft. However by removing that and using the code below it proved to not cause any issues.

```py
    def mirror_items_grouped_horizontal(self):
        items = self.scene.selectedItems()
        if not items:
            return
        
        # Calculate the collective bounding box
        bounds = QtCore.QRectF()
        for item in items:
            bounds = bounds.united(item.sceneBoundingRect())
        origin = bounds.center()

        # mirror and offset
        for item in items:
            item_origin = item.sceneBoundingRect().center()

            # mirrored offset
            delta_x = (origin.x()-item_origin.x()) * 2.0

            # Apply the final transformation
            tm = QtGui.QTransform()
            tm.scale(-1, 1)
            item.setTransform(tm * item.transform())

            # Offset object to make the mirroring appear centered on the object
            new_origin = item.sceneBoundingRect().center()
            offset_x = (item_origin - new_origin).x() + delta_x
            item.moveBy(offset_x, 0)
```

Comment: Uhm, I'm not following. The code above will only reflect the item in its current center, but will not mirror the full selection (as in your original image). Note that I just realized that you could use QGraphicsItemGroup.

Comment: sorry about that, i posted the wrong code. i updated the code above to show you the updates. I'd be more than glad to show you the complete code if you are curious about the bug specifically when using the Translate feature of Transform.

Comment: No worries. Yes, I'd like to better understand the specific case (considering your alignment issue) in order to better understand the whole context. In reality, if you can, a MRE added to the original question would be even more helpful.